# Mysql Order by mix values then other values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a column in the db containing one of the following values : 1 2 3 4

I want to order according to this value in this way :

```
mix between 1 & 3 then 2 then 4.
```

Table : Services

Columns:
name , service_type

service type can be 1 2 3 4  and i want to display with order service 1 and 3 then 2 then 4

Any idea ??
Kind Regards

Comment: That is totally unclear. You need to provide the name of the table, the column names and a many more data/result examples. Otherwise this post may get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, using `case/when`:

```
create table t7
(   name varchar(20) not null,
    aNum int not null
);
insert t7 (name,aNum) values ('a',2),('z',3),('n',3),('q',4),('t',1),
('q',2),('w',3),('e',3),('r',4),('t',1),('y',2);

select name,aNum, 
CASE WHEN aNum in (1,3) THEN 1 else 2 end as theOrder 
from t7 
order by theOrder;
+------+------+----------+
| name | aNum | theOrder |
+------+------+----------+
| z    |    3 |        1 |
| n    |    3 |        1 |
| t    |    1 |        1 |
| t    |    1 |        1 |
| w    |    3 |        1 |
| e    |    3 |        1 |
| a    |    2 |        2 |
| r    |    4 |        2 |
| q    |    2 |        2 |
| q    |    4 |        2 |
| y    |    2 |        2 |
+------+------+----------+
```

If that `mix` isn't **special** enough, then go for

```
select name,aNum from
( select name,aNum from t7 where aNum in (1,3) order by rand()) x1
union all
select name,aNum from
( select name,aNum from t7 where aNum in (2,4) order by rand()) x2
```